# Highchart js max 15 plots to be plotted

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have been trying a lot in Highchart js and still cant find a way to reduce the number of elements in the series.

If i get more than 15 days data i have to reduce it back and show to user as 15 days data so that user can see the data without crowding of data. Max 90 days will be given in the series which i have to reduce to 15 days.

check my current code here in http://jsfiddle.net/MULZL/

can any one give me a solution for it ?

P.S: I dont want to reduce it to first 15 days or last 15 days. I want to do it just because getting 90days in the chart looks crowded and i dont want zoom functions to apply. I want the solution for ignoring some data (days) to make it 15days if it is more than 15 days

Comment: Have you looked at HighStock instead. It aggregates automatically. FYI, high stock renders line chart.

Comment: @SandeepGB: I dont want zooming or time line scrolling options. I just want to reduce the plotting automatically.

Comment: I think there is an option with HighStock to prevent zooming/panning and hide the bottom portion of the chart (mini-chart). I don't remember the actual setting. You need to refer the APIs/reference material.

Comment: when you reduce to 15 days, do you take first 15 or last 15 days?

Comment: Is it possible for you to get start date of data?

Comment: @JugalThakkar: Not like that it is ignoring some days in the middle to make it 15 days.

Comment: what exactly you want is to ignore some days data value and get 15 values from that but it will be a wrong way to visualize data Why dont you use Line Chart?

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed that should be needed to be explicity passed, one can find it as `chart.series[0].points[0].x`

Comment: Are you looking for reducing to 15 days or 15 points !!!! Please frame your question correctly so that people don't was time solving the wrong issue

Comment: @JugalThakkar: Sorry for framing the question wrong i updated the question now.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically zoom into the required time range using the [Axis.setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes%28%29) method. In your case you may want to do it [on load](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.Chart%28%29)

Here is how you would do it, if you want to zoom into the 1st 15 days of the given data, you can easily modify to zoom into last 15 days.

```
function zoomTo15Points(chart){
    var points=chart.series[0].points;
    if(points.length<15)   return;
    var min=points[0].x;    
    var max=points[14].x;
    // If you wish to zoom to 15 days and not 15 points, you can modify max as
    // var max=min + 1000*60*60*24*14
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min,max);    
    chart.showResetZoom();
}
```

If you do not want to let the user zoom out, you can disable the last line, but you also will have to disable zooming, else the button would appear if user zooms inside the 15 days.

[Highchart Zoom on Load @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/JraJW/)

Comment: The problem in this is that @Princeyesuraj does not want first 15 or last 15 he want valuse with some interval of days and get 15 days from 90 days.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed Yes got that, what he wants it interpolation or data grouping to 15 points and not 15 days to be precise

Comment: @JugalThakkar: Sorry for not giving the correct question. I want to ignore some data in between to make it 15days. No the first or last 15 days.

Comment: exzactly, so you change your answer according to that, If you can.

Comment: You can try dataGrouping feature of highStock, fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/JraJW/4/ Reference @ http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.column.dataGrouping

Answer (score 0):

You can try [dataGrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.column.dataGrouping) feature of highStock

```
var dataGrouping = {
    groupPixelWidth: 40,
    units: [[
        'day',
        [1, 2, 3,4,5,6]
        ]]
};
```

Highcharts would make sure all your columns are at least the specified width (40), if the number of coulmns is large, such that it's not possible to have that width, it will group data using the units, so it will group data of 1 day into 1 column or 2 days into 1 column and so on. 
Not sure if you really want exactly 15 plots, but I think you concern was to avoid crowding of data, this does exactly that, but the number of columns will vary based on the width you specify, the width of the plotArea and allowed units and its multiples. Tweak the values as per your data and width of your chart. 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/JraJW/4)