# Highstock column chart,columns are sticking to each other

Tags: highcharts

i have created an chart using highstock, but in the chart the columns are sticking to each other.[image: column sticked]

Is this the normal behaviour of Highstock version 2.4.1?
Or is it a issue. Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: I guess you are talking about columns overlapping each other , please look at this link, might solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513593/how-to-prevent-column-overlap-in-highcharts

Comment: Please set a [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange)